# Sharepoint 2013 - authentication problems

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, authorization, cookie

we have a very different setup on our client. So I will try to explain the scenario as best as I can.

- We have a Sharepoint 2013 web application that need to be authenticated in another system. So what I did: I changed the login page from Sharepoint to point to this app (same server, same domain). This application generates an authentication cookie that I add to the resquest and then I redirect it back to Sharepoint
- The Sharepoint site and this application share the same machine key so I was expecting that it would be authenticated but sharepoint sends the request back to the application as it seems to be not authenticated
- The solution gets in a lopp and I receive ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Am I missing something on this solution? Is there anyway to use this kind of authentication between the applications? How can Sharepoint understands that the user is authenticated via authentication cookie?